# Python. How to sum each element with multi times in loop?

Tags: python

Example:

```
import numpy
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(a[i]+1)
```

Here, I have b = [2,3,4,5,6].
But I want sum multi times...(maybe I want to sum with 3 times). I expected after three times sum I have b = [4,5,6,7,8].

So, how I can get b=[4,5,6,7,8] from a=[1,2,3,4,5] with 3 times add 1 with loop?

Comment: Importing `numpy` where the builtin `len` function would have sufficed‽ In fact, you don’t even need that, nor `range`…

Comment: A simple list comprehension is already good enough, so you can skip Numpy for this moment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 3 to each element using a list comprehension;

```
b = [i+3 for i in a]
```

or as a function, where you can change the value added to the list easily;

```
def add_k_to_list(k, a_list):
    return [i+k for i in a_list]
```

To repeatedly apply as per your comment;

```
def add_k_to_list(k, a_list):
    for _ in range(k):
        a_list = [i+1 for i in a_list]
    return(a_list)
```

Comment: I mean after I add 1 to each element 3 times. Of course, I know add 3 is okey but thank you so much!

Comment: I've added a final version that increments each element by +1 `k` times